# iPhone - OpenCV Libraries Built for armv7

Tags: iphone, ios5, opencv, armv7, armv6

I've been working with the precompiled OpenCV libraries available at [eosgarden](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/) since last summer. When trying to submit our app to the app store, we noticed that if the deployment target is set to iOS 5 you are required to support the **armv7** architecture. We can only support devices running iOS 5, but our app is built for **armv6** because the version of OpenCV we originally downloaded was also built for armv6 (and still is).

My question is, does anyone know of an update to this library from **eosgarden** that is built for **armv7**? Is there a way to recompile these libraries?

This is my build errors:
**ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jinser/Desktop/TAapp/TAMenuApp/OpenCV/lib/iPhoneOS/lib/libcv.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)**
I get the same thing for **libcxcore.a**, **libcvaux.a**, **libml.a**, **libhighgui.a**.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced my eosgarden implementation with this nice easy framework.

http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

Thank you Robin Summerhill and Aptogo.