# OpenCV for armv7s doesn't include merge or split method?

Tags: ios, opencv, ios6

I used the compiled version of OpenCV for armv7s that can be found here :

https://github.com/hammer498

I use the grabcut function, which works, as some others function

but when i use merge or split method, i got error during compilation

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
>   "cv::merge(std::vector > const&,
>   cv::_OutputArray const&)", referenced from:
>         -[GrabcutVC startGrabcut] in GrabcutVC.o   "cv::split(cv::Mat const&, std::vector >&)", referenced
>   from:
>         -[GrabcutVC startGrabcut] in GrabcutVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s

Did i miss something ?

This post is a bit related to

[OpenCV.Framework does not compile for the armv7s architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491046/opencv-framework-does-not-compile-for-the-armv7s-architecture)

I wanted to post a comment but my reputation is too low

Hammer, i hope you can see this post :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what would be causing your problem.  My solution is now outdated though because opencv [2.4.3](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#243) comes with support for armv7s.  I would recommend downloading and using it.

Comment: I have resolved my problem with this answer by changing CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++.
my openCV version is 2.4.8

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and fixed it by changing "C++ Standard Library" to `libc++`:

```
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++
```

Previously I had it set to Compiler Default.